# How to create stored procedure to update multiple rows from C#

Tags: c#, sql

How to create a stored procedure to do the same function as this code does?

```
string sql = "Update Product set ProductName='" + Product.Name + "' where ProductId=" + Product.Id + "";

foreach (var item in Product.pros)
{
    sql += "Update ProductProperties set PropertyValue ='" + item.PropertyValue + "' where PropertyId =" + item.PropertyId + " and ProductId =" + Product.Id + "";
}

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

Comment: Maybe go read about stored procedures? This looks so basic, it's almost page 1 in the book.

Comment: "translate this code for me" is not an appropriate "question" for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Blorgbeard, in my code i made loop through collection to make update statement for every item in the collection. my question is how can i do the same with stored procedure... my confusion is how to make stored procedure and looping.... Thank you

Comment: That will be **highly dependent** on what concrete RDBMS you're using - **SQL** is just the *query language* - used by many database systems - but the actual syntax and features available depends on whether you're using `sql-server`, `oracle`, `postgresql`, `mysql` or something else entirely. Please tag your question with the actual RDBMS you're using!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [table valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). We used to do really ugly stuff like passing comma-delimited strings to procedures and splitting them up so that we wouldn't have to make multiple procedure calls, or we'd pass XML. This came out in 2008 and it's much easier.

In your database you would declare the type:

```
CREATE TYPE ProductUpdateTableType AS TABLE 
    (productId int, propertyId int, propertyValue varchar(20));
```

(Just guessing/making up the data types.)

Then in your stored procedure you would use the parameter like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProducts
    @productUpdates ProductUpdateTableType READONLY
AS
UPDATE products set propertyValue = updates.propertyValue
FROM
    ProductProperties product 
    JOIN @productUpdates updates
        on product.productId = updates.productId
        and product.propertyId = updates.propertyId
```

You're using the parameter like it's a table.

On the C# side you'd need to create a `DataTable` and add columns to it that match your table type. Then you would add rows containing the individual values. I usually create a class like this:

```
public class ProductUpdateParameter : DataTable
{
    public ProductUpdateParameter()
    {
        Columns.Add("productId", typeof (int));
        Columns.Add("propertyId", typeof (int));
        Columns.Add("propertyValue", typeof (string));
        Columns[2].MaxLength = 20;
    }

    public void AddProductUpdate(int productId, int propertyId, string propertyValue)
    {
        Rows.Add(productId, propertyId, propertyValue);
    }
}
```

That way you create an instance of `ProductUpdateParameter` and add as many items as needed.
Then, when calling your procedure, you would do it like this:

```
    var updateParameter = new SqlParameter("@productUpdates", SqlDbType.Structured);
    updateParameter.TypeName = "dbo.ProductUpdateTableType";
    updateParameter.Value = [your data table]
```

Then add that parameter to your `SqlCommand` and execute it.